# Using ServiceLocatorFactoryBean of Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am creating third part login system for my web application using Oauth2 and have to support various third party Oauth2.0 service provider like

1. Gmail
2. Facebook
3. MSN
4. Yahoo
5. Twitter

I have already working code for these.Each service provider have a certain set of configuration which need to be created before starting Oauth process.I was thinking about using `ServiceLocatorFactoryBean` of Spring and create few services for each Oauth provider and based on what user has selected can fetch that specific service.

Is my approach is good enough or is it like a overuse / overcomplicated one

**Edit**

As per one answer, We can create a single bean with singleton scope and inject Map of required services to it so as we can fetch services from Map based on what user has selected, though approach is fine but won't that force us to load every services in Memory and no matter if we will use them or not, they will remain in Memory

Answer (score 3):

Using ServiceLocatorFactoryBean is a way to do it and solves the problem of getting a bean (implementing an interface) based on a String key lookup.

The [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ServiceLocatorFactoryBean.html) says that the class is meant mostly for injecting prototype scoped beans, but also works for other scopes altough they don't advise it.

The javadoc gives an indication that is not the use case for which the ServiceLocatorFactoryBean was created, another solution that gives the same work is to just create a singleton bean OAuthServiceProvider that returns the correct service depending on a string using just some if/elses or a map.

In the long run it would more readable, the use of the ServiceLocatorFactoryBean seems not to buy us much compared to that.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but using a single bean and have a Map of services is more or less same approach,We will need to read all those services at start-up and no matter if we will use them or not, they will remain in the memory all time